# How to kill same group process

Tags: linux, process, kill

How to kill a process initiated by another user, who is in same group as me?

Comment: What's wrong with `kill -15 PID`?

Comment: @Bobby permission denied

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that: What's wrong with `[sudo|su|impersonate other user] kill -15 PID`? Just because you're in the same group, doesn't mean that you're allowed to touch his belongs

Answer (score 3):

As Bobby already mentioned in comments, being in same group do not allow you to kill process.

Try running

```
sudo kill PID
```

where PID is process identifier of that process.

If you do not have sudo access (or root password), you are out of luck.